# How can I authenticate to AWS via SAML ADFS?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, saml, boto, adfs

I have been having problems with running the samlapi.py script detailed on this page:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-implement-federated-api-and-cli-access-using-saml-2-0-and-ad-fs/

I am following everything correctly, but I continue to run into errors such as this:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "./samlapi.py", line 6, in <module> import boto.sts  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto.sts'`

Even though I DID install boto.

As well as...

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/chrisroarke/samlapi.py", line 8, in <module> import requests  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'`

Even though I DID install requests-ntlm.

I am following the instructions on this article and continue to run into these issues. Very frustrating. I am on MacOS, running Big Sur, Python3.9, have installed 'beautiful soup' as well as 'requests-ntlm' as instructed; I just don't know why it cannot seem to find these modules.

If anyone out there has run into this issue and has a potential solution to propose I'm all ears and would greatly appreciate it!

Cheers - Chris

Comment: These are some of useful reference from AWS;
1) [Set up ADFS as a SAML identity provider with an Amazon Cognito user pool](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cognito-ad-fs-saml/)
2) [Grant my Active Directory users access to the API or AWS CLI with AD FS](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/adfs-grant-ad-access-api-cli/)
3) [AWS Federated Authentication with Active Directory Federation Services (AD FS)] (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/aws-federated-authentication-with-active-directory-federation-services-ad-fs/)

Comment: Suggestion - In case you stick to current solution, then instead of using boto, using boto3 is better. option

Comment: Hi - Thanks for the suggestion. I definitely installed boto3. But - the boto3 installed in the Python 2.7 directory instead of the Python 3.9 directory which is the version I want to use. Why are the modules defaulting to the 2.7 directory? Can I force them to install in the 3.9 directory?